# $F \le E$ extension. every element $\alpha \in E - \overline{F}_E$ over $\overline{F}_E$ transcendental

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, extension-field

Let $F \le E$ be a field extension. Prove that every element $\alpha \in E \setminus \overline{F}_E$ over $\overline{F}_E$ transcendental.

Note: $\overline{F}_E = \{x \in E  : x  \text{ is algebraic over } F \}$.

**Edit:** If $\alpha$ algebraic over $\overline{F}_E$ then $\overline{F}_E (\alpha)$ is algebraic over $\overline{F}_E$ and so $\overline{F}_E$ is algebraic over $F$. Hence $\overline{F}_E(\alpha)$ is algebraic over F and $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$.

Can you help me?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what definition of transcendental are you using?

Comment: @masiewpao Not algebraic elements.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question, I thought you were asking about whether it is transcendental over $F$, which is obvious by definition

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\overline F_E$, i.e.,
$$\alpha^n+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+\dots+a_1\alpha+a_0=0,$$
for $a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\in\overline F_E$. Let $K=F(a_0,\dots,a_{n-1})$. Clearly $K$ is a finite extension over $F$. The above equation shows that $[K(\alpha):K]\le n$, and thus
$$[K(\alpha):F(\alpha)][F(\alpha):F]=[K(\alpha):F]=[K(\alpha):K][K:F]<\infty.$$
Since $[F(\alpha):F]$ is finite, $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$.